# Cannot retrieve more than one result from a recordset

Tags: java, jdbc

This code retrieves only 1 record from the database.

How to retrieve the rest records from the database using the next button

```
public void Next()
{
  Connection con=null;
  ResultSet rs=null;

  try {
    con=DBConnection();
    Statement stmt=con.createStatement();
    rs= stmt.executeQuery("select * from info where id=1");

    while(rs.next())
    {            
      t1.setText(rs.getString("Name"));
      t2.setText(rs.getString("Branch"));             
    }
  } catch (Exception e) {
    // TODO: handle exception
  }finally{
    try {
      rs.close();
    } catch (SQLException err) {
      JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(btnnext, err.getMessage());
      // TODO: handle exception
    }
  }
  //return rs;
}
```

Comment: In your loop, you always change the same objects t1 and t2. So only the last row matters.

Comment: but on the click of next button its fetching only 1 record from the database....

Comment: how to fetch the rest records

Answer (score 3):

First do this in 2 step:

Create a database connection outside the next() method, unless, you can't fetch other records:

```
    Connection con=null;
    ResultSet rs=null;

    try {
        con=DBConnection();
        rs = con.createStatement().executeQuery("select * from info where id=1");
    }
```

Second, iterate on the Query:

```
public boolean Next()

{
 if(!rs.next()) { //if no next then we should deactivate the next button
   return false;
  } else {
  t1.setText(rs.getString("Name"));
  t2.setText(rs.getString("Branch")); 
  return true;
  }
}
```

Also please make sure that the following query:

> select * from info where id=1

will return more than 1 row, you could try using a query which has no where and returns more row.

Answer (score 1):

Put data into **list**.

```
List<SomeObject> list = new ArrayList();
        while(rs.next())
                     {
          SomeObject obj = new SomeObject();
          obj.setName(rs.getString("Name"));
          obj.setBranch(rs.getString("Branch"));
          list.add(obj);
                     }
```

Now you can use **list** to extract data.

And SomeObject :

```
  public class SomeObject {

    String name;
    String branch;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getBranch() {
        return branch;
    }

    public void setBranch(String branch) {
        this.branch = branch;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming `Next()`<sup>1</sup> is the method executed each time your button is pressed. If so, then you need to ensure you save your `ResultSet` *outside* this method so that you can cycle through the results each time the button is pressed.

Currently you are executing the query and then cycling to the last record every time your button is pressed.

<sup>1</sup> *Use [Java naming conventions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/codeconventions-135099.html#367) and start your method with a lowercase 'n'*

Answer (score 0):

setText() inside a While loop doesn't make sense. it will always return you the last row.
You should put your records inside a list with in the While loop and do what ever you want with it outside.